# Priority of template constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constructor

I have the template class Foo:

```
template<class T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) = default;
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
    Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = default;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = default;

    template<class U, typename = typename std::enable_if<
            !std::is_same<typename std::decay<U>::type, Foo>::value>::type>
    Foo(U&&) {

    }
};

int main() {
    Foo<int> ff;
    Foo<char> dd(ff); //here I want a compiler error
    Foo<int> e(15); //it should work
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to add constraints about template constructor, however this code compiles so I think I'm missing something, what's the proper way to add the enable_if?

Comment: Remove the `!` before `std::is_same`.

Comment: @songyuanyao is probably right... or - did you _intended_ to say "doesn't decay into `Foo`"?

Comment: BTW: In which case the SFINAE constructor should take place over the other Foo constructor types and why? If you really remove `!` I have no idea what the sense of the template constructor should be!

Comment: @einpoklum mabye I'm confused, I wanted to say apply it when it's not Foo, so "doesn't decay into Foo" the same thing?

Comment: I adjusted the question because with or without ! it doesn't work. The main should be say what I want now

Comment: @greywolf82: My answer addresses the reason your code doesn't work, neither with the `!` nor without it. Also, it's usually better to explain what you want to achieve in human language in addition to providing the code, exactly for the case of the intent differing than what's implemented.

Comment: Simply add `Foo(T)` and remove the template stuff? Maybe I totally misunderstand the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `main()` function, you're trying to construct a `Foo<char>` from a `Foo<int>`. A decay-based ctor will *not* work here, as `Foo<A>` does not decay into `Foo<B>` even if `A` decays into `B`. See [the cppreference page on `std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) for a detailed explanation of what it does, exactly.

Also, I would suggest avoiding explicit (templated) constructors from pre-decay types. If your argument too one of the copy or move constructors (from `const Foo&` and `Foo&&` respectively) decays into a `Foo`, then those ctors should be enough. And if they somehow aren't, this implicit conversion that you're allowing for is probably more trouble than it's worth. It will certainly make your class more difficult to read and to adapt. You have, in fact, already seen it has led you to a minor bug :-P

Comment: Yep, it's the seond part of your reply. How can I adjust the condition then?

Comment: @greywolf82: You could write `Foo(const Foo<U>&)` and `Foo(Foo<U>&&)` constructors, with the condition of `U` decayable into `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the typo, you can also make use of the **deleted function declaration** as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
template<class T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) = default;
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
    Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = default;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = default;

    
    template<typename K, typename = typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<T, K>>>
    Foo (Foo<K> const&) = delete;
    
  
};

int main() {
    Foo<int> ff;
    Foo<int> gg(ff); //THIS WORKS
    //Foo<char> dd(ff); //THIS PRODUCES ERROR
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/zZifeJ0gu)